# Is LinkedIn API allowing to access all user profiles?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are interested to integrate LinkedIn into our CRM database to see where the people are up to now (changed job) based on person name and the current company name. Is this possible? As far as I know the API is restricted by the Linked credential and limited by his/her connections, is this right?

If it's correct, is there any LinkedIn API premium that we can access to achieve what we want then?

We know that the LinkedIn has a product called Sales Navigator and based on the demo looks like it's possible but the person has to be tagged first or something like that.

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a person profile after authentication, As of May 12th Linkedin has restricted the use of API Blog [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/todays-changes).

According to which you may only access Basic Profile(Name,Picture,Headline,Title,Location,Current Position) for Full Profile Access you would need to Apply with Linkedin for a Partner Account. 
"is there any LinkedIn API premium that we can access ?" Yes , Here is the Link to Premium [link](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr)

"see where the people are up to now (changed job) based on person name and the current company name. Is this possible?" Yes in permission r_fullprofile there is a field isCurrent which is true for a current company and false for previous companies. You can also get a start date and end date for companies.

To get user connections ask for r_network permission. For a connection Profile you only get the Name,Profile Pic,Headline,Industry and link to connections linkedin profile

Have a Look at these links :

Data Fields : [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields)

Transition Guide : [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition)

API Terms of Use : [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use)

Comment: I believe that the 'r_network' permission is being removed. It works for some users now, but its likely to change at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the public api right now. You used to be able to, so if you apply for the [Partner Program] (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply) you should be able to get access to the features you want. This is only from my experience from what I was able to access in the past. It's worth applying to see if that data is still available to partners.

You can look at what is available through the public api right here.
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?authTypeVal=oauth2&afterSuccessfulAuth=true

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but some configuration with LinkedIn apps and i have integrate LinkedIn in Our Product. if you want to search any particular person information when first of configure LinkedIn Developer apps and get App ID and APP Secret Key and set as a default permission in your app settings or requested specifically via the scope argument during your authentication process after you will get Access Token then any user login and with your apps and authorize when you will get all profile information of authorize user

see this document may be helpful 
[click here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)

LinkedIn Throttle Limits

1. Application maximum : 100,000
2. Per individual user :   n/a
3. Per individual developer :  n/a